# Validate textarea after change value by JS

Tags: javascript, html, validation, textarea

I want validate `textarea` after change value by JS but then validation not working. I want use "pure" JS

`minlength` is set as `5`. When you change value by Add button and try validate then validation will not work. It shoud be validated like by normal typing `12`

```html
<textarea name="textarea" minlength="5" maxlength="30" required></textarea>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('textarea').value = '12';">Add</button>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('textarea').reportValidity();">Check</button>
```

Comment: how is the validation not working? what is the expected behavior?

Comment: `minlength` is set as `5`. When you change value by Add button and try validate then validation will not work. What is the expected behavior? Validation like by normal typing

Comment: Your code has an extra quote: `'12';""` should be `'12';"`.

Comment: @ggorlen It not changing nothing. Still not working https://jsfiddle.net/h7m8zast/10/

Comment: Please define "not working". What is your expected behavior?

Comment: @ggorlen Look my update

Comment: It interestingly works when you call `setCustomValidity()` before `reportValidity` (but that defeats the supposed advantages of having minlength/maxlength). I tried introspecting on `validationMessage` so one could at least grab the default message browser but that wasn't set either.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to wrap the text area in a  element and then run the `reportValidity()` on that element.

Comment: Changed exaple to add text by `innerText` and still validation not working https://jsfiddle.net/h7m8zast/3/